# Workbench conecta con el servicio mysql pero el xampp no conecta

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Workbench conecta con `mysql` y tengo varias bases de datos allí, por cmd de windows también puedo entrar y modificar las bases de datos, pero cuando utilizo `xampp` específicamente el shell de xampp para ingresar a las bases de datos luego de ingresar el user y password (`mysql -h localhost -u root -pmi_clave`) me tira este error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on localhost (10061)

Lo mismo ocurre con `phpmyadmin`:

> "No se estableció conexión los parametros estan incorrectos."

Quiero manipular las bases de datos desde phpmyadmin pero no me deja.

Como dato, el servicio `mysql` corre en el puerto `3306` mientras que en `xampp` lo tengo configurado en el puerto `3307`.

Anteriormente no tenía problemas, todo empezó cuando cambie la contraseña en `phpmyadmin` y ya no quiso entrar.

Para ingresar a la base de datos por cmd de windows y workbench tengo contraseña y no me da problemas.

Comment: Al crear un usuario tienes la opción de host name donde puedes indicar que la conexión sea en localhost o any o desde una ip en concreto. Creo que el error que te da veien de ahí. El usuario con el que intentas acceder no tiene permisos para acceder desde donde estas.

Comment: *«Como dato, el servicio mysql corre en el puerto 3306 mientras que en xampp lo tengo configurado en el puerto 3307»*  ... ¿por qué esa divergencia de puertos, acaso no deberías configurar el mismo puerto para ambos casos? Prueba el comando indicando el puerto: `mysql -h localhost -u root -p mi_clave --port 3306` o bien: `mysql -h localhost -u root -p mi_clave --port 3307` Si sigue sin funcionar, verifica que el servicio `mysql`  está ejecutándose realmente. Otra cosa, no sé si fue un error al escribir la pregunta, pero esto lo tenías todo junto: `-pmi_clave` lo cual es erróneo.

Comment: El host name lo cree en localhost, en ambos tanto workbench como phpmyadmin. Y el usuario "root" es el único activo en ambos. Sólo que en workbench tiene contraseña. Ahora la divergencia de puertos es porque cuando instalé el xampp este no me dejaba correr el servicio dado que el puerto ya estaba siendo usado (Workbench) por eso tuve que modificarlo a 3307

Answer (score 3):

Cuando tienes mysql y xampp (incorpora su propio mysql), tienes 2 servicios mysql corriendo (ambos se configuran por defecto en el puerto 3306).

En tu caso mysql => quieres tenerlo con su puerto por defecto 3306 y a Xampp => cambiarlo a 3307 por problemas de conflicto:

Prueba esto:

1. En Xampp Control Panel > my.ini ... busca esta linea "port=3306" y cambiala a 3307 (aparece 2 veces)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. En Xampp Control Panel > config > service and port settings > pestaña MySql:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    cambia Main Port a 3307
```

Saludos espero haya ayudado a los que tienen problema similar...

Comment: Me fue de mucha utilizada esta solución muchas gracias